# Angular : An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/ParserHelpers'

Tags: angular, angular-material, node-modules

I want to do an upgrade from Angular 7 to 8.
I have installed @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.800.0, uninstalled et reinstalled node modules, but I always got this problem : Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/ParserHelpers'
When I did npm fix audit I got another type of error which is : An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist. See "C:\Users\Surface\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-urmmUP\angular-errors.log" for further details.[image]

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue. Any luck on resolving this? I've tried everything I was able to find so far to no avail.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, make sure that NPM is up-to-date.

```
npm i -g npm
```

Check version of Webpack. The **version 5** (and after) is not currently supported by @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.8XX.X ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18556)).

Clean all :

remove node_modules folder and package-lock.json file

```
rm package-lock.json && rm -R node_modules
```

remove dist folder

Clear npm cache :

```
npm cache clean --force
```

To see which version are installed :

```
npm ls webpack
```

How to resolve ?

```
npm uninstall webpack
npm install --save-dev webpack@4.39.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it has been solved

1. npm audit fix / sudo npm audit fix (ubuntu)
2. Adding the following code in tsconfig.json
   "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "enableIvy": false
   }

Comment: Unfortunately for me neither

Answer (score 0):

you can use npm ci

[description](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171556855892/introducing-npm-ci-for-faster-more-reliable.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while working with npm workspaces. You can add to your `package.json`:

- Without using the npm workspace (and therefore having [the issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4834)), i guess the following should work:

```json
"overrides": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29": {
    "worker-plugin": {
      "webpack": "^4.39.2"
     }
  }
}
```

- However, i fixed it with:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  // You other dev dependencies here
  "webpack": "^4.39.2"
},
"overrides": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29": {
    "worker-plugin": {
      "webpack": "^4.39.2"
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You Should check your webpack version in Package-lock.json and package.json

Comment: What version should we expect ? Or how can we know which version should be expected ?