# npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Im junior and I dont know resolve this:

```
  npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
  npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
  npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
  npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

package.json:

Comment: You need `MacOS` in order to install and use this library, as stated in the [README](https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents#troubleshooting), so you can't install this package because you are using `linux`.

Comment: I resolved this with this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443175/angular-an-unhandled-exception-occurred-cannot-find-module-webpack-lib-parse

Comment: I got the same error deploying a MERN app to render.com. I guess it was a compatibility issue between package-lock.json and package.json.
Run npm ci ,after that I ran a npm audit fix. 
That did for me.